# Nav Bar Not Working On Specifically Home Page | Enjin

Tags: html

So I have a website that uses enjin as a base and custom code on top of that. (not working as in hovering over the options doesn't make their drop downs appear as it does on other pages)

For some reason  on my home page **only** the nav bar at the top doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Clicking on the "Enlist Today" button takes you to the application page where the navigation bar **does** work and it's confusing the life out of me.

Any help?

Website in question: http://www.142airbornedivision.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is javascript:; if you omit it your page works fine.

```
<a href="javascript:;" target="_self">
```

If you wrote href for make a tag valid, instead of a tag you can use button because you created your navigation bar with divs

Comment: Well thats the thing I didnt create the nav bar at all since its created through enjin. Also it only doesn't work on the page specified